# Long footnotes with longtable

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have a long footnote to add to a table. I am using the option `threeparttable = TRUE` so the text is wrapped correctly. However, this is causing the footnote to go before the table and not at the end as I want. Is there a way to make the footnote to go at the end of the table? It seems to be related to the option `longtable = TRUE` which I need to use.

[image]

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'kableExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     group_rows

long_text <- "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

mtcars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  kable(
    "latex",
    longtable = TRUE,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    escape = FALSE
  ) %>%
  kable_styling(
    latex_options = c("repeat_header"),
    font_size = 4
  ) %>%
  footnote(general = long_text, threeparttable = T, fixed_small_size = T)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: somehow I can't reproduce the error :( [here is a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/OR6jmcH.png)

Comment: are u using it in rmarkdown

Comment: Not using rmarkdown. I am just creating a table1.tex file that I import later in my main .tex file.

Comment: are u importing `booktabs,threeparttable,threeparttablex`

Comment: Thank you @AbdessabourMtk this was exactly the problem.

Comment: Also notice that before the `\endfoot` is empty I'd suggest adding a `\bottomrule` as to not keep the end of table on each page blank